# Object [object Object] has no method 'jqChart'

Tags: jquery, jqchart

Here are my javascript files:

```
<script src="Js/JqStuff/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="MetroJs.Full.0.9.75a/MetroJs.js"></script>
<script src="Js/JqStuff/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.11/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<script src="Js/JqStuff/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Js/JqStuff/jquery.jqChart.min.js"></script>
<script src="Js/JqStuff/jquery.jqRangeSlider.min.js"></script>
<script src="testjs.js"></script>
```

In my **test.js**, I have made a function which creates a chart, but it gives an error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var background = {
        type: 'linearGradient',
        x0: 0,
        y0: 0,
        x1: 0,
        y1: 1,
        colorStops: [{ offset: 0, color: '#d2e6c9' },
                     { offset: 1, color: 'white' }]
    };

    $('#jqChart').jqChart({
        title: { text: 'Pie Chart Labels' },
        legend: { title: 'Countries' },
        border: { strokeStyle: '#6ba851' },
        background: background,
        animation: { duration: 1 },
        shadows: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'pie',
                fillStyles: ['#418CF0', '#FCB441', '#E0400A', '#056492', '#BFBFBF', '#1A3B69', '#FFE382'],
                labels: {
                    stringFormat: '%.1f%%',
                    valueType: 'percentage',
                    font: '15px sans-serif',
                    fillStyle: 'black'
                },
                explodedRadius: 10,
                explodedSlices: [5],
                data: [['United States', 65], ['United Kingdom', 58], ['Germany', 30],
                       ['India', 60], ['Russia', 65], ['China', 75]],
                labelsPosition: 'outside', // inside, outside
                labelsAlign: 'circle', // circle, column
                labelsExtend: 20,
                leaderLineWidth: 1,
                leaderLineStrokeStyle: 'black'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Here is my **HTML**:

```
<div id="jqChart" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Kindly guide me to what I'm doing wrong. I already checked that all my **.js** files are included once.

Here is the **error:**

> [image]

Comment: The jqChart plugin isn't loaded... check your network tab and verify the script gets loaded.

Comment: @tymeJV...what you mean is `jquery.jqChart.min.js`??

Comment: Yes...  look at your network tab in the console and verify the script is loaded.

Comment: I verfied all the js files are properly loaded, no error on loading

Comment: Do you have multiple JQuery versions loaded? If so you need to either remove them or use `jQuery.noConflict();` before your JQuery code.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle demo depicting this issue.

Comment: `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)`